# Should Game Genre Types Be Capitalised?

Tags: technical-writing

I am currently writing a report for college about computer games and I am wondering whether genres need to be capitalised. Usually I do not but for some reason it just feels that I should.

For example:

"The game is in the adventure genre."

or

"The game is in the Adventure genre."

I am tempted to go with the latter because it is the name of a genre and names need to be capitalised.

Thank you,

Shane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a proper adjective, and therefore should not be capitalized. The name "adventure" is generic. It's not like saying "This game is in the Zork genre," referring to a particular early game.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely - not. (With exception: when it will be common to write "Thriller", "Romance" or "Historical".)

Answer (score 1):

No, don't capitalize those.

But you would never say that a game is in the adventure *genre* anyway. You would simply say that it is an adventure, or an adventure game. If more explanation is needed, say it is "an interactive text adventure in the Infocom tradition" or whatever.